# Is each element of factor(von Neumann algebra) a linear combination of projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a factor von Neumann algebra. Then every element of $A$ can be writeen as a finite linear combination of projections in $A$. Is it right? I know a little about von Neumann algebra, thanks a lot to the one who tell me the answer or tell me where I can find the answer.

factor means $A\cap A'=\mathbb{C}I$.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The introduction to [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2013-365-05/S0002-9947-2013-05683-8/S0002-9947-2013-05683-8.pdf)  by Kaftal et al mentions several references that address this question.

Answer (score 2):

In

*Pearcy, C.; Topping, D.*, [**Sums of small numbers of idempotents**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1028999848), Mich. Math. J. 14, 453-465 (1967). [ZBL0156.38102](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0156.38102).

it is proved that such representation is possible in any properly infinite von Neumann algebra.

Comment: @Norbert: Thank you! It is a nice theorem in the paper. But here the von Neumann algebra is a factor.

Comment: @TomCooney I've fixed that mistake

Comment: @Norbert:Thank you again. What is  properly infinite von Neumann algebra?

Comment: They are direc integrals of properly infinite factors (which are factors whose identinity is not a finite projection). For dettails see this wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra

Comment: Excuse me ,  the link is not available.

Comment: @mathbeginner fixed